# Using Action Script 3.0 to Control Button Rollovers

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert action script 2.0 code to 3.0 and am having trouble. I have multiple buttons I'm working with and want each one to go to and stop at a certain frame when rolled over and go back to frame 1 when rolled out.

I am not very well versed when it comes to coding, I can get this code to work for one button, but when I apply it to another, I get errors and it essentially is playing all the frames.

```
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseOver);
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseEnabled = true;
    buttonMode = true;
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create single class for a generic simple button. You apply this class to a movieclip in your library by going: library -> your_symbol -> *rightclick* -> properties -> **class**. You can then drag as many instances of this symbols on the stage and they will all work.

If you need variations in some buttons (e.g. adding sounds on hover), you extend the **SimpleButton** class and overload the methods. This usually results in many little classes, which is why you should store them in a **buttons package** :)

```
package buttons {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class SimpleButton extends MovieClip {

        public function SimpleButton() {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mOver);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mOut);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mDown);

            buttonMode = true;
        }
        protected function mOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        protected function mOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
            gotoAndStop(1);
        }
        protected function mDown(e:MouseEvent):void {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that by the time your code is in onMouseOver, it lost it's reference to the button where the event occurred. 
To find the button that got the event you can use e.currentTarget.

And you don't need mouseEnabled and buttonMode - by the time it got there you can be sure your button is set.

So the code would be

```
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onMouseOver);
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(3);
}

function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

or even shorter version would be

```
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function (e:MouseEvent) {    e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(3);    });
button_201c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function (e:MouseEvent) {    e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(1);    });
```